# Difference between select txid_current and select txid_current_snapshot

Tags: postgresql, transactions

have the below

```
  Select txid_current();
Result:txid 004
Begin;
Insert into tab values(2,45);
Insert into tab values(3,56);
Commit;
```

Now when I do

```
Select txid_current();
It txid shows :006
txid_current_snapshot();
```

Shows txid:05

What is the difference between both

Answer (score 3):

Nice question.

**txid_current_snapshot** is textual representation is xmin:xmax:xip_list. For example 10:20:10,14,15 means xmin=10, xmax=20, xip_list=10, 14, 15.

> xmin  Earliest transaction ID (txid) that is still active. All earlier
>   transactions will either be committed and visible, or rolled back and
>   dead.
>
> xmax  First as-yet-unassigned txid. All txids later than this one are
>   not yet started as of the time of the snapshot, and thus invisible.
>
> xip_list  Active txids at the time of the snapshot. All of them are
>   between xmin and xmax. A txid that is xmin <= txid < xmax and not in
>   this list was already completed at the time of the snapshot, and thus
>   either visible or dead according to its commit status.

When you play in terminal you cannot see difference but when you have a lot of parallel transactions you can.